# from the shellscript one option has been chosen OR none of them

Tags: bash, shell

am not expert on bash script and am looking help on. I would like to find a way at the end from the while loop condition that the script can be executed unless one option (**[-1|-2|-3]**) has been chosen OR none of them.

What the best way to do? I have absolutely no idea how to.
Many Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "  $0 [-e <option_e>] [-f <option_f>]  [-1|-2|-3] [user@]fqdn"

OPTION1=""
OPTION2=""
OPTION3=""

while (( "$#" )); do
    if [ "$1" == "-1" ]; then
        OPTION1=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-2" ]; then
        OPTION2=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-3" ]; then
        OPTION3=1
    fi

   shift
done
```

I forgot to mention. this is a part of the script. further, there are several conditions that can conflict if there more then 2 options chosen.

EDIT: the valid selections either exactly one option or zero, but not two or more!

Comment: Initialize a counter variable to 0 before looping, loop over the arguments as you currently do, increasing the counter when one of your expected options is matched. At the end of the loop, exit with error if the counter is greater than 1.

Comment: At the end of the loop the condition is NEVER met because one option *([-1|-2|-3])*  OR none is ALWAYS satisfied...

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco. yes, you totally right. what I forgot to say is that it's a part of my script.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you write "the script can be executed unless one option has been chosen or none of them". Did you mean ***can't*** be executed? So, are the valid selections either exactly one option or zero, but not two or more?

Comment: @BenjaminW. that true! the valid selections either exactly one option or zero, but not two or more !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you SamuelKirschner -
I did to add [[ -n $ALL_OPTS ]] &&   then it works ! I am happy now.

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTION1=""
OPTION2=""
OPTION3=""

while (( "$#" )); do
    if [ "$1" == "-1" ]; then
        OPTION1=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-2" ]; then
        OPTION2=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-3" ]; then
        OPTION3=1
    fi

   shift
done

ALL_OPTS="$OPTION1$OPTION2$OPTION3";
echo $ALL_OPTS
if [[ -n $ALL_OPTS ]] && [[ $ALL_OPTS -ge 2 ]];then
    echo 'Please provide a maximum of one of the options [-1|-2|-3]' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Nice thinking, that works as well (because when `$ALL_OPTS` is 11 or 111 it is grater than 2 when used as a decimal number). My original idea was that `${#ALL_OPTS}` (the length of $ALL_OPTS) should be grater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply test if all of the OPTION-variables concated have the wrong length with `ALL_OPTS="$OPTION1$OPTION2$OPTION3"; test ${#ALL_OPTS} -ge 2` and exit. Where `"$OPTION1$OPTION2$OPTION3"` is just all of the variables written next to each other, therefor it is "", "1", "11" or "111".

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "  $0 [-e <option_e>] [-f <option_f>]  [-1|-2|-3] [user@]fqdn"

OPTION1=""
OPTION2=""
OPTION3=""

while (( "$#" )); do
    if [ "$1" == "-1" ]; then
        OPTION1=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-2" ]; then
        OPTION2=1
    elif [ "$1" == "-3" ]; then
        OPTION3=1
    fi

   shift
done

ALL_OPTS="$OPTION1$OPTION2$OPTION3";
if test ${#ALL_OPTS} -ge 2; then
    echo 'Please provide a maximum of one of the options [-1|-2|-3]' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

From `man bash`

> ${#parameter}
>
> Parameter length. The length in characters of the value of parameter is substituted. [...]

*Edit: I messed up the condition quite a bit. (original answer was `test -z "$OPTION1$OPTION2$OPTION3"`)*

Comment: That's what I want. on the other hand, Do you know why the output for more then 2 characters is "unary operator expected" and if I choose all of them "binary operator expected"

Comment: @ren I think I used some bash incompatible escaping, could you try the variant (just edited the answer) with `test ${#ALL_OPTS} -ge 2`

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a count of options might be a possibility. Something like this, using [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${0##*/} [-e <option_e>] [-f <option_f>]  [-1|-2|-3] [user@]fqdn"

count=0

while getopts e:f:123 opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    e) opt_e="$OPTARG" ;;
    f) opt_f="$OPTARG" ;;
    1|2|3) declare opt_$opt=true; ((count++)) ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# Fail if our counter is too high
((count>1)) && printf 'ERROR: only one digit option allowed.\n' >&2 && exit 1

echo "done"
```

Alternately, you could keep the numeric options in a variable which you could check using globs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${0##*/} [-e <option_e>] [-f <option_f>]  [-1|-2|-3] [user@]fqdn"

nopt=""

while getopts e:f:123 opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    e|f) declare opt_$opt="$OPTARG" ;;
    1|2|3) nopt="$nopt$opt" ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

# Fail if we collected too many digits
((${#nopt}>1)) && printf 'ERROR: only one digit option allowed.\n' >&2 && exit 1

echo "done"
```

Then, you could switch functionality based on the value of `$nopt`.